# Is there a useful way to represent the optical theorem in the parametric representation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

The usual way to represent the optical theorem for Feynman diagrams is through the Cutkosky rules. The proof of these rules works by considering the momentum representation and performing the iterated integrals while keeping track of the origin of the singularities. An account of this is given in "The analytic S-Matrix" by Eden, Landshoff, Olive and Polkinghorne on pages 111-112.

My goal is to understand the optical theorem in the parametric representation (as given e.g. in Itzykson, Zuber - Quantum Field Theory in chapter 6-2-3). Is there a way to use similar reasoning as in the momentum representation? After all the expression is again an iterated integral, where one could in principal trace the singularities. My problem is that the graph polynomials give a way more complicated singularity structure in terms of the alpha parameters compared to the relatively simple on-shell poles of the momentum representation.